# Apply different function to each subgroup

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My data has 3 columns - `person_id`, `group_id` and `score`.
Each person might have multiple records in different `group_id`. I would like to apply a function on the score of each person per `group_id`. For example, apply some aggregate function for `person 0` and `group_id 0` and the same function for `person 1` `group_id 0` but different function for `group_id 1`.
I know how to do it with a for loop but on a big data set it is very inefficient. Any ideas how to do it with `groupby`?

Here is some code:

```
n = 100
person_id = np.random.randint(0,10,size=n)
group_id = np.random.randint(0,3,size=n)
score = np.random.rand(n)

df = pd.DataFrame([person_id,group_id,score]).T
df.columns = ['PERSON_ID','GROUP_ID','SCORE']

score_summary = []
for person in df['PERSON_ID'].unique():
    idx0 = (df['PERSON_ID'].values==person) & (df['GROUP_ID'].values==0)
    score0 = np.mean(5.0*df.loc[idx0,'SCORE']+2)
    idx1 = (df['PERSON_ID'].values==person) & (df['GROUP_ID'].values==1)
    score1 = np.mean(6.0*df.loc[idx1,'SCORE']+2)
    idx2 = (df['PERSON_ID'].values==person) & (df['GROUP_ID'].values==2)
    score2 = np.mean(5.0*df.loc[idx2,'SCORE']+3)
    score_summary.append({'PERSON_ID':person,
                          'SCORE0': score0,
                          'SCORE1': score1,
                          'SCORE2': score2})

df_summary = pd.DataFrame(score_summary)
df_summary.head()
```

Edit:

I found another approach that seems to work much faster (orders of magnitude) on large data sets:

```
df['NEW_SCORE'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['GROUP_ID']==0,'NEW_SCORE'] = df.loc[df['GROUP_ID']==0,'SCORE'].apply(lambda x: 5.0*x+2).values.reshape(-1)
df.loc[df['GROUP_ID']==1,'NEW_SCORE'] = df.loc[df['GROUP_ID']==1,'SCORE'].apply(lambda x: 6.0*x+2).values.reshape(-1)
df.loc[df['GROUP_ID']==2,'NEW_SCORE'] = df.loc[df['GROUP_ID']==2,'SCORE'].apply(lambda x: 5.0*x+3).values.reshape(-1)
df1 = df.groupby(['PERSON_ID','GROUP_ID']).mean()
df_summary2 = df1.reset_index().pivot('PERSON_ID','GROUP_ID','NEW_SCORE')
```

Comment: I put forward an inferior solution (performance-wise), albeit requiring only 6 lines. I am hoping there is a better solution to this.

Comment: If you found a solution, post an answer to your own question, and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The issue, by design, with `groupby` is that only one series is passed. You need to perform some hacks to check Group_Id value when grouping by Person_Id. This seems to be expensive.

Therefore, I find your solution efficient. However, if you really want to cut code and performance is not an issue, you can use `df.groupby.apply` as below.

```
n = 100
person_id = np.random.randint(0,10,size=n)
group_id = np.random.randint(0,3,size=n)
score = np.random.rand(n)

df = pd.DataFrame([person_id,group_id,score]).T
df.columns = ['PERSON_ID','GROUP_ID','SCORE']

df = pd.concat([df]*1000)

def original(df):
    score_summary = []
    for person in df['PERSON_ID'].unique():
        idx0 = (df['PERSON_ID'].values==person) & (df['GROUP_ID'].values==0)
        score0 = np.mean(5.0*df.loc[idx0,'SCORE']+2)
        idx1 = (df['PERSON_ID'].values==person) & (df['GROUP_ID'].values==1)
        score1 = np.mean(6.0*df.loc[idx1,'SCORE']+2)
        idx2 = (df['PERSON_ID'].values==person) & (df['GROUP_ID'].values==2)
        score2 = np.mean(5.0*df.loc[idx2,'SCORE']+3)
        score_summary.append({'PERSON_ID':person,
                              'SCORE0': score0,
                              'SCORE1': score1,
                              'SCORE2': score2})

    df_summary = pd.DataFrame(score_summary)
    return df_summary

def jp(df):

    idx = {k: set(df[df['GROUP_ID'] == k].index) for k in (0, 1, 2)}
    d = {0: (5, 2), 1: (6, 2), 2: (5, 3)}

    def func(x):        
        return tuple(d[k][0] * np.mean(x[x.index.isin(idx[k])]) + d[k][1] \
                     for k in (0, 1, 2))

    return df.groupby(['PERSON_ID'])['SCORE'].apply(func).reset_index()


%timeit original(df)  # 39.7ms
%timeit jp(df)        # 78ms
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think the problem with my solution is the repetitive search for the right index for each person and group id. When the data gets really large (+ more people) it becomes really inefficient.

Comment: @EyalS., if you do find a better solution, do post it. Otherwise, I might offer a bounty on this question myself.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating separate user-defined functions and pass into an `groupby().agg()`:

```
def s1(x):
    return np.mean(5.0 * x + 2)

def s2(x):
    return np.mean(6.0 * x + 2)

def s3(x):
    return np.mean(5.0 * x + 3)

df_summary = df.groupby(['PERSON_ID', 'GROUP_ID']).agg([s1, s2, s3])

df_summary.head()  # USE np.random.seed(222) TO REPRODUCE

#                        SCORE                    
#                          s1        s2        s3
# PERSON_ID GROUP_ID                              
# 0.0       0.0       3.209123  3.450948  4.209123
#           2.0       5.295679  5.954815  6.295679
# 1.0       0.0       5.012666  5.615199  6.012666
#           2.0       4.621171  5.145406  5.621171
# 2.0       0.0       3.926392  4.311670  4.926392
```

Comment: Yes, but this is doing 3x more calculations than necessary (given 3 groups). As number of Group_Ids grows, this wouldn't work. I already see it (not surprisingly) ~3x slower than OP.

Answer (score 0):

I found an efficient way (time wise) to perform the task. It is still not that efficient code wise but for larger data sets it performs much faster than the for loop solution:

```
df['NEW_SCORE'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['GROUP_ID']==0,'NEW_SCORE'] = df.loc[df['GROUP_ID']==0,'SCORE'].apply(lambda x: 5.0*x+2).values.reshape(-1)
df.loc[df['GROUP_ID']==1,'NEW_SCORE'] = df.loc[df['GROUP_ID']==1,'SCORE'].apply(lambda x: 6.0*x+2).values.reshape(-1)
df.loc[df['GROUP_ID']==2,'NEW_SCORE'] = df.loc[df['GROUP_ID']==2,'SCORE'].apply(lambda x: 5.0*x+3).values.reshape(-1)
df1 = df.groupby(['PERSON_ID','GROUP_ID']).mean()
df_summary2 = df1.reset_index().pivot('PERSON_ID','GROUP_ID','NEW_SCORE')
```

Comment: I still see this slower than OP, and slightly slower than my naïve effort for `df = pd.concat([df]*50000)`.